# sql query results show null when data exist

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

Alright well my original code is longer but this will be simple and get my point across. Below is a sample of the code.

```
USE lme_1030
SELECT invoice_no
FROM billing_history
WHERE ship_date >= DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE())
ORDER BY invoice_no
```

When executed it proves only null values even though data should exist.  Any ideas of what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Check column type for `ship_date`. Syntactically you query is correct.

Comment: Null values or no value returned ?